# disable days in rich faces 4 calendar component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using two ric:calendar one for start date and another for end date.

the end date should disable all the previous dates automatically based on the start date selection.

Can it be possible using dayDisableClass?

Comment: This is a step by step example which show you how to highlight and disable certain days.

  http://www.tech-lead.blogspot.com/2012/10/highlight-certain-dates-in-component.html

It may looks little complex. But its not such difficult. Note the line 
`modelItem.setEnabled(true);` It does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Regadring the `disabledDay` way...

take a look at this post: [Disable days on rich:Calendar](http://devharbor.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/disable-days-on-richcalendar.html)

Also you can use the calendar `CalendarDataModel` -> `CalendarDataModelItem` -> `isEnabled()`

```
Boolean isEnabled() returns "true" if date is "selectable" on the calendar, the default implementation returns "true"
```

take a look at the [Demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=dataModel&skin=blueSky)

Comment: can it be possible only from client side using <h:outputScrpit>

Comment: take a look at the link I posted in my answer... http://devharbor.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/disable-days-on-richcalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use calendar's attribute **dayDisableFunction** and define your JavaScript function which would define which days are disabled:

```
<rich:calendar dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction" ...</rich:calendar>
```

example JS function:

```
function disablementFunction(day) {
    if (day.isWeekend) return false;
    return true;
}
```